# How to get Max rating post in CakePHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm new to PHP and I don't understand how to get only the post that has the maximum rating

```
 $all= $this->Post ->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id'), 'recursive' => -1, 'limit' => 2));
```

I want to only show the post which has the maximum rating.

```
[0] => Array
(
    [Post ] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Gramercy Tavern 
        [contact] => 
        [cuisine] => 
        [rslug] => gramercy-tavern
        [state] => NY
        [rating] => 2
        [created_date_time] => 2017-10-14 16:42:10
    )
)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want the Post with the best Rating?

Comment: For example. ORDER BY rating DESC, LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

To get the Post with the best rating, you just need to order by this field and only ask for the first one:

```
$post = $this->Post->find('first', array(
    'order' => array('rating' => 'desc')
));
```